# Vertex between other vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a paper on graph theory (On Disjoint Paths in Planar Graphs) and in an algorithm  they define the set N to be the vertices between S1 and S2. But I'm wondering what exactly defines a vertex to be 'between' two other vertices: is U between S1 and S2  when there is a edge (S1, U) and (U, S2) or is there some other definition? I tried searching on internet but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two vertex sets $ S_1,S_2\subset V(G) $ we may say that a vertex $v \in V(G) -S_1\cup S_2$ is between $S_1$ and $S_2$ if it lies on some path between two vertices $x \in  S_1$ and $y \in S_2$.

By the way, a path between $x$ and $y$ can be thought of as a sequence of alternating adjacent vertices and edges, starting at $x$ and stopping at $y$

Comment: I cant see the difference between my answer and yours; I'm wondering why you post the exact same answer after my answer!

Comment: @AliAmiri, cool story bro.

Answer (score 0):

No, Consider the path between S1 and S2, suppose that this path contain the several vertices the set N that mentioned in book is this set of vertices, but it is possible there were a multiple path between to vertices like S1 and S2 so you must consider all this paths, although if you write the whole theorem and it's proof I could explain this much more better.